# What is the best practice for using MongoClient.connect in an Express app with lots of routers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an app that does this kind of thing multiple times:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
    //work with db data
  });
});
```

But then I heard somewhere that it's better practice to connect to the database once, and use that connection on the whole thing. So does that mean something like this?:

```
MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //do some stuff
  });        
  app.get('/other', function(req, res){
    //do some stuff
  });
  //
  //more routers....
  //
});
```

So which of these two methods would be considered better practice? And what makes it better? What is the difference? And is there a better way?

Comment: The "best practice" is to connect to your database "once", and not per request. There is significant overhead in creating database connections which adds time to every request. It's is also not great to be opening and closing collections all of the time. There are many examples of follwing a "singleton pattern" for your database collection. As well there are many libraries that already do this for you, so you do not need to re-invent the wheel again.

Answer (score 0):

Connect once, watch for connection errors:

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
var dbConnection = mongoose.connection;
dbConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
dbConnection.once('open', function callback() { console.log('DB opened'); });
```

Use `dbConnection` when you need to database access.